# How to show this measure is positive?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $(E,M,\mu)$ be a measured space with non-zero $\mu$, and let $f:(E,M)\to(\mathbb R, B(\mathbb R))$ be a measurable function. Show that for all $\epsilon > 0 $, there exists $A\in M$ such that $\mu(A)>0$ and

$$\forall x,y\in A, |f(x)-f(y)|\leq \epsilon$$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Let $\epsilon>0$, and let $I_n = [n \frac{\epsilon}{2}, (n+1)\frac{\epsilon}{2})$.

Some details:

> Then $E = \cup_n f^{-1} I_n$, and this union is disjoint, hence $\mu E = \sum_n \mu (f^{-1} I_n)$. Since $\mu E >0$, then for at least one index $k$, we have  $\mu (f^{-1} I_k)>0$.

More details:

> Let $A = f^{-1} I_k$. Then if $x,y \in A$, we have $f(x),f(y) \in [k \frac{\epsilon}{2}, (k+1)\frac{\epsilon}{2})$, and so $|f(x)-f(y)| < \epsilon$.